# Отобразить три модели на одной странице панели администратора Django

Tags: python, django

Я делаю страницу для просмотра расписания занятий студентов. Есть 3 модели:

- `SelectGroup`
- `SelectDate`
- `Lessons`

Мне нужно отобразить их в панели администратора Django таким образом, чтобы `SelectDate` была вложенной моделью к модели `SelectGroup`, а модель `Lessons` была вложенной моделью `SelectDate`, то есть получается модель в модели в модели.

Вот код моделей

```
class SelectGroup(models.Model):
    selgroup = models.OneToOneField(Groups,
                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                    verbose_name='Група',
                                    unique=False)
    main = models.ForeignKey('Main', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lesson = models.ForeignKey('Lessons', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Розклад'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Розклад'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.selgroup.groups

class SelectDate(models.Model):
    dateday = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата',
                               unique=False)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Дата'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Дата'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.dateday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

class Lessons(models.Model):
    groups = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                              default="----",
                              unique=False)
    date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата',
                            default=current_time,
                            unique=False)
    account = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True,
                                  verbose_name='Пара №',
                                  unique=False,
                                  validators=[MinValueValidator(1),
                                              MaxValueValidator(6)])
    start_time = models.TimeField(verbose_name='Початок пари',
                                  unique=False)
    end_time = models.TimeField(verbose_name='Кінець пари',
                                unique=False)
    discipline = models.CharField(max_length=100,
                                  verbose_name='Дисципліна',
                                  unique=False)
    audience = models.CharField(max_length=5,
                                verbose_name='Аудиторія',
                                unique=False)
    teacher = models.CharField(max_length=150,
                               verbose_name='Викладач',
                               unique=False)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Розклад'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Розклад'

    def __str__(self):
        return ''
```

Пробовал следующий вариант регистрации:

```
class LessonsInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Lessons
    fields = ['account', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'discipline', 'audience', 'teacher']
    extra = 1

class SelectDateInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = SelectDate
    inlines = [LessonsInline]
    fields = ['dateday']
    extra = 0


class SelectGroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ['lesson']
    inlines = [SelectDateInline]

admin.site.register(SelectGroup, SelectGroupAdmin)
```

Тогда получается, что инлайн модель `Lessons` не отображается в модели `SelectDate`, помогите решить данную проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно то, что ты ищешь [django-nested-inline](https://pypi.org/project/django-nested-inline/)

```
pip install django-nested-inline
```

Comment: А стандартными методами никак?

Comment: Видимо если существует библиотека, то без танцев с бубном никак, может кто-нибудь подскажет, я не сталкивался с этой проблемой